# Using exchange services to send meeting invites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spfx, microsoft-graph, exchange-online

There is a add-in available from Sharepoint Sapiens in which they are sending email invites to user (internal and external).
They ask for a email id from which emails should be sent, once added, the account is authorized and meeting invites are sent to users from the above configured email id.

I want to understand how they are doing it, as it is not possible using graph api that, being logged in as User A, a meeting is scheduled in your calender but the organizer is user whose email we configured above.
The above said add-in uses graph api but all permissions are delegated.

Permissions : Directory.ReadWrite.All

Comment: Have you contacted them to ask?

Comment: App is available on store, can be downloaded for trial, all the steps that I mentioned are taken when apps is installed, and permissions can be checked from sharepoint admin center.